# Getting rid of thin separating line above Navbar, Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 for my website. I have the usual `.navbar` on the page, and it works well, except for one thing that's out of my fashion. There's like a little dividing line between the `.navbar-collapse` and `.navbar-header` when the screen shrinks to the hamburger menu. I've boldened it in the pic.

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <title>Stuson.com</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Stuson.com is a social media platform for students, by students.">
    <meta name="author" content="Stuson Dev Team">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css\essentials.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control hidden-xs" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Search</span>
            </button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/essentials.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## CSS

```
#noBorder {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
#transparent {
  background-color: transparent;
}
body {
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.navbar {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #38ba7d;
}
.navbar .navbar-header {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-header > .navbar-toggle,
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse ul li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse form input {
  width: 250px;
}
@media (max-width: 786px) {
  .navbar .navbar-collapse form input {
    width: 10px;
  }
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse form .btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

[image: That unimpressive line!]

How can I avoid this? I've tried using `border: none` on both `.navbar-collapse` and `.navbar-header`, but to no avail.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the 'border' is caused by a `box-shadow`, so add this:

```
.navbar .navbar-collapse{
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS code snippet:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
        border: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting .navbar-default or .navbar-inverse to 0 should do the trick.

```
.navbar-default {
   border: 0;
}
```